# How can I use Observables in an Angular2 component while handling errors or allowing subsequent array access?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

This may be two related questions. I have several angular2 components that make async requests to a service and display results once received. The reactive way would be do do this with an Observable that the template is bound to directly. However, I find that often I need to handle errors in those subscriptions in my component code. I can't figure how to do both simultaneously, so I typically end up assigning the async result to a property and handling errors inside a zone.run() instead.

Additionally, I often need to map arrays returned from a service call to add stuff like an `isSelected` property for selection tracking, then later inspect the array to find the selection, like:

```html
refreshTeamItems() {
  this.apiService.getProgramTeams()
    .map(teams =>
      teams.map(team => ({
        team,
        selected: false
      }))
    )
    .subscribe(items => {
      this.zone.run(() => this.teamItems = items);
    }, err => /* handle err */ );
}
```

So, in general my question is how do I make my service layer Observables more useful in my component code rather than just naively handing them off to the template? I'm assuming there's some nice reactive composable way to do this, but I'm not an rxjs pro.

Comment: Why don't you use the second callback to `subscribe` to handle errors?

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. I can certainly do that in the above example. My question was how to do this in the case that I expose an Observable directly to the template vs. using zone.run + an intermediate property such as teamItems.

Comment: Added error handler to example for clarity.

Comment: I don't see the point of using this.zone.run(), but I also don't see anything wrong with doing it the way you're doing it. If you really don't want to subscribe from the component, but want to handle errors, use the catch operator: `.catch(error => {this.handleError(error); return Observable.throw(error); })`

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking the catch operator may do the trick for that case, but I couldn't find a clear example. zone.run() is because the subscription callback is async and is called outside of angular's change detection mechanism.

Comment: @snort no, it's not. Zone.js precisely allows knowing when an asynchronous callback is executed. That's the whole point.

Comment: I guess I'm confused about examples I've seen and the behavior I'm getting then. Without calling within zone my UI never updates, unless I instead use ChangeDetectorRef to force an update. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @JBNizet my initial assumption about zones was exactly as you say, and after some re-reading I see that is the intent. Still trying to figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Ugh. Obviously it was some other error on my part. I've removed the zone.run() calls, and it works just as it should. Thanks for the tip.